# how to add virtual dirctory inside the virtual directory in iis 7

Tags: iis-7

I like to create virtual directory like http:\localhost\program\c#\helloworld\Login.aspx. Such as to create virtual directory inside the c# inside the program. Can anyone tell Is this possible.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to explicitly create the virtual directory during run-time. You may as well create just the folder using the System.IO objects. Though, I doubt if "C#" is a valid name inside a url string.